# Send string to another process stdin

Tags: linux, bash, process, proc, stdin

Example process waiting an input sent to background

```
$ read -p "Input text and hit ENTER to exit" &
```

I try to write to stdin (fd/0) with \n

```
$ echo -e "ok\n" > /proc/$!/fd/0
```

but

```
$ fg

read -p "Please hit ENTER"
```

so the process is still running, then string "ok\n" never reach it

How can I send a string+ENTER to another process STDIN?

Comment: What to you want to achieve with that? Maybe another way would also be OK (like setting a default value before, and use timeout parameter `-t` for `read`)?

Comment: to achieve = send ENTER from stdout one to another process stdin